# View page doesn't output but views_embed_view with same arguments does?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with a page display. A simple view with a few content types to display, and a contextual filter for taxonomy.

If I enter an argument in the views preview, it works as expected. Displays "no results found" for gibberish, and properly filtered nodes for taxonomy terms that exist.

If I put a views_embed_view in the page template with a hard-coded argument, it also displays as expected.

```
<?php print views_embed_view('explore', 'explore', 'About-Us'); ?>
```

My problem is that if I go to the page path www.site.com/explore/About-Us I get nothing. No errors, no "No results" dialog, no results. The content array is completely empty.

I've done dozens of views pages, with arguments and without, and never had this problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew the answer would be stupid.

I had registered the path I was using for my view's page in a module a couple months ago and forgot. ><